# evaluating the security risk of exposing a row's identity in the querystring

Tags: security, query-string

Is it a security risk to expose the ID number of a SQL row?

For example, there is an event with an ID of 12.

Is it a security concern if someone accesses it via `http://example.com/events/12`, or someone makes a POST to `http://example.com/events/12` in order to update that record (assuming I allow this of course)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem of exposing ID's to users is often referred to as "insecure direct object references" in a web security context.

From [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References):

Preventing insecure direct object references requires selecting an approach for protecting each user accessible object (e.g., object number, filename):

1. Use per user or session indirect object references. This prevents
   attackers from directly targeting unauthorized resources. For
   example, instead of using the resource’s database key, a drop down
   list of six resources authorized for the current user could use the
   numbers 1 to 6 to indicate which value the user selected. The
   application has to map the per-user indirect reference back to the
   actual database key on the server. OWASP’s ESAPI includes both
   sequential and random access reference maps that developers can use
   to eliminate direct object references.
2. Check access. Each use of a direct object reference from an
   untrusted source must include an access control check to ensure the
   user is authorized for the requested object.

A defense in depth approach would be to do both 1 & 2.

Answer (score 2):

Whether to display or not, it doesn't matter.

What matters is that you check that the caller is authenticated and is authorized to perform the operation being requested.

Someone may have a bot spitting out requests to `http://example/events/x` where x is an incrementing number. Perhaps it's a snoopy employee trying to view `http://payroll/employee/x`.

Authenticate the user to ensure that they are who they say they are. Forms authentication, LDAP, what have you.

Ensure the user has authorization to perform each action when called. Usually the user belongs to a group that has permission to update the boss' salary, create a shipment, or cancel a credit card.

If you implement measures as above, the source of the `id` won't matter, whether it's on the cookie, hidden form element, querystring, session variable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

URLs and querystrings are particularly insecure when you're using integer identifiers. After all, if there is a 12, there is almost certainly an 11 or a 10. GUIDs make it harder to guess another item, but still shouldn't be considered secure IMJO.

Bottom line: You need some sort of authentication mechanism to ensure that the user is who he claims to be, and authorization mechanism to ensure that he is allowed to see what you are about to show him.